# OS X (10.9.1) localhost 403 Forbidden you don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

I have just started using laravel and a mac to develop websites. I have gone through the setup and tried following a phpacademy tutorial.

My problem is that when i try and access the localhost, as default i get the index page where all my folders are stored and when i enter my direct path e.g. laravelpractice.local in the web browser i get the error that i mentioned in the title.

i have edited the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and the /etc/hosts to create a virtual host and create a custom url respectively and the spelling seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/hosts file open. You must be the owner of the file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

after add

```
127.0.0.1 laravelpractice.local
```

000-default.config file save. After /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.config file open. You must be the owner of the file. Add to the bottom

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravelpractice/public/"
    ServerName laravelpractice.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache restart with terminal:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Open browser and url : laravelpractice.local

Comment: Yep that worked but i also had to change the permissions i had in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf folder as it was set to _www and not my actual user. when i changed all that and restarted apache it worked fine thanks for your support! sorry that my original post was not correctly formatted.